# Delphi - How to calculate the border-width of a SpeedButton

Tags: delphi

How can I calculate the exact width of the border of a `TSpeedButton`?

Depending on the values of the `Flat` and `Down` properties it seems to have a different width and a text starts at a different pixel. (with `Margin <> -1` and no glyph set)

Delphi 10.2.3

Comment: You should look at source code, you've got it! Check "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\source\vcl\Vcl.Buttons.pas"

Comment: @BigBother: "... or any other directory in which you installed your copy of Delphi or C++Builder.". In my case, that would be a different one.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis of course, i left it as a homework! ;-)